# Erro no upload de temas Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou tentando fazer o upload de um tema wordpress cujo o tamanho é de 40MB. Sempre que tento fazer o upload, o arquivo carrega todo e no final aparece o erro: "413 Request Entity Too Large". Como resolvo o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso voce consegue configurar no seu `php.ini`, tem que aumentar o limite de upload, `upload_max_filesize` e `post_max_size`.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 45M
```

Um detalhe importante é que o `post_max_size` é o tamanho máximo do post, isso inclui os textos/dados de um formulário, que voce envia junto com um arquivo, então se mandar um arquivo com exatamente 40mb e mais um campo `nome` por exemplo, pode dar problema. Então acho sempre bom deixar o `post_max_size` um pouco maior do que o tamanho máximo do arquivo.

Comment: Qual o caminho do arquivo? Não estou achando ele aqui

Comment: Da uma googlada de acordo o SO e pacote que esta usando, nao sei se  voce usa Linuz, Windows, Mac, se instalaou na mao ou se esta usando algum AMP da vida, MAMP, WAMP, XAMP, LAMP, e por ai vai.

Comment: Uma dica é criar uma pagina com `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` e procurar por `Loaded Configuration File` lá vai estar o caminho do seu `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

em primeiro lugar: descompactou o ficheiro do theme?
se sim, e parto do principio que sim:

caso esteja a trabalhar com o Wordpress em localhost,
copie o template de wordpress para o respectivo local que o cliente que estiver a usar tenha usado para criar uma conta de servidor local

caso esteja a trabalhar num servidor na web:
use o FileZilla, ou então copie o template a partir de ssh, por bash, ou com o comando ftp por bash, para aceder a conta do servidor que estiver a usar, com as respectivas credenciais, para desenvolver o site, e copie os ficheiros do seu computador para lá ja descompactados.

na sequência disto configure o template dentro do seu backoffice de Wordpress